# How can I submit a form multiple times according to a for-loop?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, for-loop

I'm using asp.net C# MVC3 with razor templates and want to know the following:

I have a form, this form contains a button. If I click on the button the following code will be executed:

```
function OnGetSelectedFieldValues(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $("#id").val(result[i]); //This will replace the value of my hidden field with the selected id
        $("#DeleteForm").submit();
    }
}
```

According to my logic this should submit and delete each row that I have selected from my gridview.
It does select each record, this I have tested with an Javascript "alert()".
But it only deletes the first record, why does this happen and how do I fix this?

Regards,

Marco

Edit:
This is my form(for easier understanding):

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "DeleteForm" }))
    {
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Verwijder geselecteerde" />
    }
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        ErrorRepository repo = new ErrorRepository();
        var test = repo.GetById(id);
        repo.Delete(test);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: You should just submit all of the values at once and handle iterating over them in your C# code. Don't do multiple `POST` requests.

Comment: In general this looks like a bad approach. you should try to have one request for all deletions to save traffic and latency. this also can cause issues with your webserver configuration i.e. if you have some sort of anti flooding security filter installed (or even later in production)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are doing a direct POST on the form, it will only execute the first time through the loop as the form will already be posting by the time it gets to the next loop through.

This is not the proper way to handle multiple deletes but if you must do it this way you'll need to create an AJAX post method so that multiple deletes can happen asynchronously.

The better way would be to pass the full list of ID's to delete to the form POST and then delete them all at once on the server side. You should build a string of comma separated ID's and send that to the POST method. Then in the method use

```
    var _ids = values.split(',');
    foreach(var _id in _ids){
        YourDeleteMethod(Int32.Parse(_id));
    }
```

If you must do it through multiple posts, you'll want something like:

```
function OnGetSelectedFieldValues(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $.post("yourPostURL",  result[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting you, I am fairly new to asp.net C#. I have in my controller a HttpPost with a public ActionResult Delete(int id), I am passing the id to the controller, how can I add multiple id's at once.

Comment: edit your Delete method to accept a string instead, so: 

`Delete(string id)`

then loop through each id that is passed in and convert it back to an integer for each delete operation:

`var _ids = id.Split(',');
foreach(var_id in _ids){
  YourDeleteMethod(Int32.Parse(_id));
}`

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Super simple now I look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only submit 1 form per page a time, try to implement a way to delete multiple records by one request!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do this? I am fairly new to asp.net C#.